Installing software under home folder (i.e., on other than root partition)
Due to space issues, I would like to install some software under the home folder, let it be LibreOffice, third party paid software or Firefox. 
That's because I partitioned my disk and the root folder is always full. 
How can I do it?
Disclaimer: unfortunately, I am a noob.

What exactly your question? Is it possible or no?

In this day and age, other then very specific (and niche) settings, having a separated /home is neither useful nor recommended. Have your personal files in a separated data partition is fine. If your self-assessment is "noob" then you really shouldn't. Any automated installation of any mainstream distro makes /home inside of root, so should you. If you insist in doing it differently then you must know what you're doing. The root partition (not a folder) always full suggests you don't.

You're not giving me much to go on but here is what I would do to run Libre out of my homedir.
(Note the * will be replaced with whatever libres version is now)

# First, create a directory in your home folder where you’ll install the software:

mkdir -p ~/apps

# Extract LibreOffice from your Downloads to ~/apps
cd ~/Downloads
tar -xvf LibreOffice_*.tar.gz -C ~/apps

# Create a symbolic link for LibreOffice so Ubuntu OS sees it.
sudo ln -s ~/apps/LibreOffice_*/LibreOffice /usr/local/bin/libreoffice

# Execute libra office to test your symlink works
LibreOffice

# If that works you may also want to add LibreOffice to your PATH
echo "export PATH=$PATH:~/apps/LibreOffice_*/LibreOffice/program" >> ~/.bashrc


Hey Michael, I think there's one major issue here, which is that linking a program from your user directory into a system path like /usr/local/bin/ can cause problems if some other user account tries to run that program, or even if it just thinks it can run that program. I'd suggest removing the sudo ln -s line from your script, and instead just execute the program with its full path. Other than that, this seems like a fine approach - slightly non-standard, but not in a way that would be likely to mess anything up.
